Threejs canvas does not scale back when phone rotated back
I am using three js library, when i rotate my phone my component basically increases its size, but when i flip my phone back it does not change back, it distorts my page and half of the component goes outside the page, how to make it responsive?
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";


export default function THREE_scene({container}) {
  const sizes = {
    width:window.innerWidth,
    height: 700,
  };

  const canvas = useRef(null);
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, sizes.width / sizes.height);
  var renderer;

  camera.position.set(35.6, 37.8, -24.5);
  camera.lookAt(-2.28, 0.75, 2.47);

  const light = new THREE.PointLight("#FFFFFF", 1000, 100);
  light.position.set(20, 28, -10);
  scene.add(light);
  scene.add(camera);
  scene.background = new THREE.Color("#000000");

  function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas.current });
    
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
  }

  loader.load("./globe.glb", (gtlf) => {
    scene.add(gtlf.scene);

   
    renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
  });

  function animate(timestamp) {
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    scene.children[2].children[0].rotation.y = timestamp / 10000;
    
  }



  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    init()
    canvas.current.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.current.height=window.innerHeight
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
   
    
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    renderer.render(camera,scene)
    
    
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
   
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas id="webgl"  ref={canvas}></canvas>
    </div>
  );
}



enter image description here
.......................................................

Try adding this function, and effect hook. And is highly recommended to use in your scenario R3F. If only because in your case Canvas is natively responsive there.
function respCanvas() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

useEffect(() => {
    init();
    window.addEventListener("resize", respCanvas);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", respCanvas);
    };
}, []);

UPDATE 0
I suspected that's what you meant… and that, creating a quite big headache, when you have many of objects in canvas. If is one that not big deal, but if you have many, well, anyway.
In this scenario, scaling canvas will determine reaction stuff, inside this canvas.
So, you have to separately adjust canvas and objects, in your case globe.
You can make this in vanilla, but also in GSAP, to listen resizing.
And with this case also R3F will not help you, still is better to use it, but natively there, responsive is Canvas, not objects.
let model;
let landscapeScale = 15;
let portraitScale = 2;

//…

function resizeModel() {
    if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
      model.scale.set(landscapeScale, landscapeScale, landscapeScale);
    } else {
      model.scale.set(portraitScale, portraitScale, portraitScale);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
init();
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  resizeCanvas();
  resizeModel();
});
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", () => {
  resizeModel();
});
return () => {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
  window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", resizeModel);
};
}, []);

https://codepen.io/Lucas_Mas/full/BaeZYxO

Now its the same, but object became flatter

@TakeshiSzentagothai Mmm what do you mean flatter? I suspect what you mean. However, could you make a CodePen for this problem?

Cant deploy react on codepen. I have got this instead. Although it does not describe the "flat" issue but this demonstrates my issue if you use phone and flip it. https://dml199.github.io/fin_adv/

I attached a file for issue below the image.

@TakeshiSzentagothai In my opinion app from your link works exactly how should… Are you talk about globe, because  doesn’t fit to portrait?

Yes, when i rotate my phone canvas scales to fit in, when i rotate back it does not scale back, only page components do, so it goes out of the page size.
